# Up or down voted content shows HTML code on vote

Tags: php, mysql

Whenever I click up or down vote on my PHP/MySQL/JS vote system, it shows long list of HTML code. I don't know what is error, some people suggested me removing `unique_content_id` because there is blank row in table for that attribute and we don't know why. I will give it a shot and post here.

Error:

http://pastebin.com/b0SQL7X4

vote_process.php file

```
if($_POST)
{

    ### connect to mySql
    $sql_con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('could not connect to database');

    //get type of vote from client
    $user_vote_type = trim($_POST["vote"]);

    //get unique content ID and sanitize it (cos we never know).
    $unique_content_id = filter_var(trim($_POST["unique_id"]),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    //Convert content ID to MD5 hash (optional)
    $unique_content_id = hash('md5', $unique_content_id);

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    }


    switch ($user_vote_type)
    {          

        ##### User liked the content #########
        case 'up':

            //check if user has already voted, determined by unique content cookie
            if (isset($_COOKIE["voted_".$unique_content_id]))
            {
                header('HTTP/1.1 500 Already Voted'); //cookie found, user has already voted
                exit(); //exit script
            }

            //get vote_up value from db using unique_content_id
            $result = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT vote_up FROM crewlist WHERE unique_content_id='$unique_content_id' LIMIT 1");
            $get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            if($get_total_rows)
            {
                //found record, update vote_up the value
                mysqli_query($sql_con,"UPDATE crewlist SET vote_up=vote_up+1 WHERE unique_content_id='$unique_content_id'");
            }else{
                //no record found, insert new record in db
                mysqli_query($sql_con,"INSERT INTO crewlist (unique_content_id, vote_up) value('$unique_content_id',1)");
            }

            setcookie("voted_".$unique_content_id, 1, time()+7200); // set cookie that expires in 2 hour "time()+7200".
            echo ($get_total_rows["vote_up"]+1); //display total liked votes
            break; 

        ##### User disliked the content #########
        case 'down':

            //check if user has already voted, determined by unique content cookie
            if (isset($_COOKIE["voted_".$unique_content_id]))
            {
                header('HTTP/1.1 500 Already Voted this Content!'); //cookie found, user has already voted
                exit(); //exit script
            }

            //get vote_up value from db using unique_content_id
            $result = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT vote_down FROM crewlist WHERE unique_content_id='$unique_content_id' LIMIT 1");
            $get_total_rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

           if (!mysqli_query($result, "SET a=1")) {
    printf("Errormessage: %s\n", mysqli_error($result));
}

            if($get_total_rows)
            {
                //found record, update vote_down the value
                mysqli_query($sql_con,"UPDATE crewlist SET vote_down=vote_down+1 WHERE unique_content_id='$unique_content_id'");
            }else{

                //no record found, insert new record in db
                mysqli_query($sql_con,"INSERT INTO crewlist (unique_content_id, vote_down) value('$unique_content_id',1)");
            }

            setcookie("voted_".$unique_content_id, 1, time()+7200);  // set cookie that expires in 2 hour "time()+7200".
            echo ($get_total_rows["vote_down"]+1);//display total disliked votes
            break; 

        ##### respond votes for each content #########     
        case 'fetch':
            //get vote_up and vote_down value from db using unique_content_id
            $result = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT vote_up,vote_down FROM crewlist WHERE unique_content_id='$unique_content_id' LIMIT 1");
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            //making sure value is not empty.
            $vote_up    = ($row["vote_up"])?$row["vote_up"]:0;
            $vote_down  = ($row["vote_down"])?$row["vote_down"]:0;

            //build array for php json
            $send_response = array('vote_up'=>$vote_up, 'vote_down'=>$vote_down);
            echo json_encode($send_response); //display json encoded values
            break;

    }

}
```

EDIT: added table rows

[image]

EDIT: please ignore everything, I had syntax error in MySQL table! instead of vote_down I had vote-down and vote_up -vote-down. I have fixed liking system it works, however whenever I click "like" it adds a new row to table. Anyone know why?

Here is my error now!

[image]

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Comment: i know i will fix @tadman after working

Comment: Doing it properly eliminates silly problems like escaping errors. It's not hard and it means you can focus on the actual problem at hand, not distractions. The "I will fix it later" line is why sites get hacked so often.